# Why do we take vector space in calculus or analysis of $n$ dimensions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I've read few topics of methods in $\mathbb{R}^n$ from books like *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by W. Rudin, *Differential Geometry* by T. J. Willmore etc.
Whenever we go to deal with Calculus or Analysis in $n$ dimensions they introduce the structure vector space (Now I know what vector spaces are and that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space) but why do we take such structure? (Edit: Why doesn't the author introduce vector space in $1$ or $2$ variables (dimensions) but only when they generalise it to $n$ dimensions/variables?)
Is it because ordinary operations like multiplication, addition subtraction don't work in $n$ dimensions? Thanks in advance.
Edit 2 : reading comments I think some people are still confused so I'll try to ask this question again in simple way "Why don't we introduce vector Spaces for 1 or 2 variable calculus (analysis) but only when we generalise it for n variables (dimensions)

Comment: Your question isn't clear, are you asking why we take a vector space instead of n dimensions?

Comment: I'm asking as we go in n dimensions why are vector spaces introduced by author , why don't they introduce this in one or two variables ( dimensions)

Comment: Because the dimension is the number of variables.
For example, let's say you you want to calculate the Total Price of you groceries, we will take 3 variables, Price, Quantity, Product, can you calculate the Total price using only Price and Quantity? No...

Comment: Also since you are familiar with the concept of vector spaces you probably know that all operations like summation, multiplication (defined for Product Spaces) are defined.

Comment: I think you've not got my question, please check the post answer of Hölderlin that's what I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

Addition and substraction work in any vector space. Multiplication is another matter. A vector space defines multiplication between scalars (elements of the underlying field) and vectors, not multiplication between vectors. The structure that implements addition and multiplication that work together as in elementary arithmetic is a field. $\mathbb R$ is a field and $\mathbb R^2$ can be defined as a field isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ that extends $\mathbb R$. As afar as I know it's not possible to make $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\geq3$ into a field that extends $\mathbb R$.

As for your other question: Calculus and (real) analysis are primarily concerned with the field of real numbers, with infinite sequences, limits, continuous functions, the derivative and the integral there. No vector spaces are needed to cover that subject. That's why they are usually not introduced right away.
Since it's not sufficient for most applications to only deal with one dimension, we do analysis on $\mathbb R^n$ or as well in general finite-dimensional Banach spaces.

Comment: This was exactly what I had doubt in , thanks sir